# Multiple affiliations of an author in sig-alternate

Tags: titles, acm

I am trying to put two affiliations for an author in [`sig-alternate`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates) (ACM SIG Proceedings), for the second author. So effectively, the second author should be over both the second and the third affiliations. But there is no way I can keep the third author field blank and have only the affiliation there. Is there any other way to do this?

```
\author{
\alignauthor
First Author\\
       \affaddr{Some lab, Some University}\\
       \affaddr{New Found Land, NJ, USA}\\
       \email{somemail@someserver.edu}
\alignauthor
Second Author\\
       \affaddr{Some lab}\\
       \affaddr{Some company}\\
       \affaddr{Santa Clara, CA, USA}\\
       \email{otheremail@company.com}
\alignauthor 
   Test author\\
       \affaddr{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}\\
       \affaddr{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}\\
       \affaddr{Hekla, Iceland}\\
       \email{larst@affiliation.org}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not clear what you're for; should "Second author" be above both affiliations?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, second author will have two affiliations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For two authors I'd go with `\and` rather than `\alignauthor`, using a nested tabular for the two affiliations:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper}

\author{%
First Author\\
  \affaddr{Some lab, Some University}\\
  \affaddr{New Found Land, NJ, USA}\\
  \email{somemail@someserver.edu}
\and
Second Author\\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \affaddr{Some lab}\\
  \affaddr{Some company}\\
  \affaddr{Santa Clara, CA, USA}\\
  \email{otheremail@company.com}
  \end{tabular}\nobreak\qquad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \affaddr{The Th{\o}rv\"ald Group}\\
  \affaddr{1 Th{\o}rv\"ald Circle}\\
  \affaddr{Hekla, Iceland}\\
  \email{larst@affiliation.org}
  \end{tabular}
}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this great proposal! It's the only answer that I found so far that doesn't really violate the template enforced by a conference. If there are not many authors (thus no space problem) this solution is just great!

Comment: is it possible to do such a simple elegant tabular solution with \author for multiple authors all with a shared affiliation? with acmsiggraph, where this one seemed to work fine.

Comment: @antont Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @egreg well what said there: how to have multiple authors with a shared affiliation? I've tried the solution in that answer but no success, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271627/shared-author-affiliation-in-acm-sig-proc?rq=1 . The one here works but for a different purpose (here many affiliations for single author, i'd need a single affiliation block under the names of all the authors)

Comment: @antont Please, make a new question with more details.

Comment: got it solved by modifying acmsiggraph.cls directly and adding a plain \begin{center} block there in the maketitle command after it lists the authros