# Multiple Non-Stupid-Looking Author Affiliations in acmart

Tags: templates, acm, affiliation

OK, so a similar question to this has [been asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101343/multiple-affiliations-of-an-author-in-sig-alternate), but it was using the old ACM style.

The new ACM LateX style, `acmart`, recommends that you use multiple `affiliation` commands to list multiple affiliations, like so:

```
\author{Baz Quux}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{University of Software Engineering}
    \streetaddress{123 Fakenstra{\ss}e}
    \city{Fakenburg}
    \country{Fakeistan}
    \postcode{POIUYT}
}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{FooCorp}
    \streetaddress{123 Fake Street}
    \city{Fakeville}
    \country{Fakeistan}
    \postcode{QWERTY}
}
\email{fake2@example.com}
```

That's all fine and dandy, but the outcome (at least to my mind) looks rather stupid and is somewhat hard to read, like so:

[image]

It also wastes vertical space (important in a tightly-spaced paper).

How can I achieve a result more like the accepted answer for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101343/multiple-affiliations-of-an-author-in-sig-alternate)?

It's been suggested that I use `\additionalaffiliation`, but unfortunately the conference insists that authors [use a version of `acmart` that doesn't have it](http://gecco-2017.sigevo.org/index.html/Papers+Submission+Instructions).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\author{Baz Quux}
\additionalaffiliation{%
    \institution{FooCorp}
    \streetaddress{123 Fake Street}
    \city{Fakeville}
    \country{Fakeistan}
    \postcode{QWERTY}
}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{University of Software Engineering}
    \streetaddress{123 Fakenstra{\ss}e}
    \city{Fakenburg}
    \country{Fakeistan}
    \postcode{POIUYT}
}
\email{fake2@example.com}
```

PS I see the conference uses the older version of `acmart`.  I guess you still can use official version from ACM which supports `\additionalaffiliation`.  I added this command specifically to address this issue.
As the last resort you can use

```
\author{Baz Quux}
\authornote{%
Also with Foo Corp.
}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{University of Software Engineering}
    \streetaddress{123 Fakenstra{\ss}e}
    \city{Fakenburg}
    \country{Fakeistan}
    \postcode{POIUYT}
}
\email{fake2@example.com}
```

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Please edit this extra information into your question...